# Opendaylight Nitrogen Dashboard (DLUX) is not accessible when installed in CentOS

Tags: opendaylight

We installed Opendaylight Nitrogen in CentOS 7. Karaf is running, DLUX, l2switch features are installed. Later we did nmap localhost to check if the port is open. You can see the stats below.
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
1099/tcp open  rmiregistry
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8083/tcp open  us-srv
8181/tcp open  unknown

Even though port 8181 is open, we were unable to login to the dashboard (dlux) and we used localhost:8181/index.html.

We installed carbon in Ubuntu 16.0 and we were able to access the dashboard and the stats for nmap localhost is the same.

Why we are not able to access dlux in ODL Nitrogen CentOS 7?

Comment: When you access http://localhost:8181, does it just "not connect" or is there a HTTP Error Response?  Is there an error message in the karaf.log?

Comment: I downloaded Firefox on CentOS server and able to access it through X11. Now I'm able to access it through local firefox by hitting the command ./firefox in my CentOS server and browsing localhost:8181.